# Why does horizontal scrollbar do not work with my JTextArea?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

Trying to read and write a text document, everything is working but the horizontal scrollbar isn't visible.

I tried to activate the JScrollPane horizontal scrollbar manually but that wasnt a result.

public class JScrollPaneÜbung extends JFrame
{

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JTextArea area;
private JTextField field;
private JScrollPane scroll;
private JButton dateisuche;
private JButton dateispeichern;
private Panel panel;
private Panel sPanel;


public JScrollPaneÜbung()
{
    area = new JTextArea(32, 41);
    field = new JTextField(30);
    scroll = new JScrollPane(area);
    dateispeichern = new JButton("Speichern");
    dateisuche = new JButton("Durchsuchen");
    panel = new Panel();
    sPanel = new Panel();
    createGUI();
}

 public void createGUI() {
        setBounds(200, 200, 600, 600);
        BorderLayout b = new BorderLayout();
        setLayout(b);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        dateisuche.addActionListener(new JScrollPaneListener(this));
        dateispeichern.addActionListener(new JScrollPaneListener(this));
        panel.add(dateisuche);
        panel.add(field);
        panel.add(scroll);
        sPanel.add(dateispeichern);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(sPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setVisible(true);

}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JScrollPaneÜbung();
}
```

No horizontal scrollbar visible, but my text document is longer than the JTextArea

Answer (score 0):

You're using a regular JPane. Use a JScrollPane instead. You can find documentation here that will guide you.
[Resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Can u show me what u mean on an example?